# PyQgis - Multiple Maps in one page with different layers in each map

Tags: pyqgis, printing

I'm trying to make a plugin for printing automatically PDF showing 3 different views from a set of layers in the same page. For this I have created a **QgsComposition** and I have added 3 **QgsComposerMap** to it. Each QgsComposer has its own zoom, and its own layers enabled or disabled.  The code for créate de QgsCompostion and two of the maps is this:

```
    # crear objeto de la clase QgsComposition
    map_settings = iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings() # Get access to properties used for map rendering
    composer = QgsComposition(map_settings)
    composer.setPlotStyle(QgsComposition.Print) # establece el tipo de impresion (preview, print, postscript)

    # establece dimensiones de papel y resolucion de impresion
    paper_width = 420.0
    paper_height = 297.0
    composer.setPaperSize(paper_width, paper_height)
    composer.setPrintResolution(100)

    # MAPA 1: 

    # intialize the map object
    map_origin_x_mm = 10
    map_origin_y_mm = 21
    map_width_mm = 190
    map_height_mm = 107.0
    composer_map = QgsComposerMap(composer,
                                  map_origin_x_mm,
                                  map_origin_y_mm,
                                  map_width_mm,
                                  map_height_mm)

    composer_map.zoomToExtent(rect)  # Zooms the map so that the specified extent is fully visible within the map item


    # Map 1 settings
    composer_map.setGridAnnotationPrecision(0)
    composer_map.setAnnotationFrameDistance(1)    
    composer_map.setAnnotationFontColor(QColor(0, 0, 0))    
    composer_map.setCrossLength(1.0)   
    composer_map.setGridEnabled(True) 

    grid_interval = 100.0
    composer_map.setGridIntervalX(grid_interval)  
    composer_map.setGridIntervalY(grid_interval) 
    composer_map.setGridPenWidth(0.1) 
    composer_map.setGridFrameWidth(1.5)  
    composer_map.setGridFrameStyle(QgsComposerMap.Zebra) 
    composer_map.setGridFramePenSize(0.2)
    composer_map.setGridPenColor(QColor(0, 176, 246))
    composer_map.setGridBlendMode(QPainter.CompositionMode_DestinationOver)
    composer_map.setShowGridAnnotation(True)  
    composer_map.setGridStyle(QgsComposerMap.Cross) 
    composer_map.setGridAnnotationPosition(QgsComposerMap.Disabled, QgsComposerMap.Top)
    composer_map.setGridAnnotationPosition(QgsComposerMap.OutsideMapFrame,QgsComposerMap.Bottom)
    composer_map.setGridAnnotationDirection(QgsComposerMap.Horizontal,QgsComposerMap.Bottom)
    composer_map.setGridAnnotationPosition(QgsComposerMap.OutsideMapFrame, QgsComposerMap.Left)
    composer_map.setGridAnnotationDirection(QgsComposerMap.Vertical,QgsComposerMap.Left)
    composer_map.setGridAnnotationPosition(QgsComposerMap.Disabled, QgsComposerMap.Right)

    composer.addComposerMap(composer_map) 
    iface.mapCanvas().freeze(False)

     #SEGUNDO MAPA: P
     factor_escala_zoom = 2
     iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(rect)
     scale_map_canvas = iface.mapCanvas().scale()
     rect.scale(factor_escala_zoom)
     scale_map_canvas_factor = scale_map_canvas * factor_escala_zoom

     #HERE I HAVE A FUNCTION TO ENABLE/DISABLE THE LAYERS I WANT IN THE MAP
     activarCapas(2)


     iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
     iface.mapCanvas().freeze(True)

     # intialize the map object
     map_origin_x_mm = 215
     map_origin_y_mm = 21
     map_width_mm = 195
     map_height_mm = 234.0
     composer_map_2 = QgsComposerMap(composer,
                          map_origin_x_mm,
                          map_origin_y_mm,
                          map_width_mm,
                          map_height_mm)
     composer_map_2.zoomToExtent(rect)  

     # Create the map grid
     composer_map_2.setGridAnnotationPrecision(0)  
     composer_map_2.setAnnotationFrameDistance(1)  
     composer_map_2.setAnnotationFontColor(QColor(0, 0, 0))  
     composer_map_2.setCrossLength(1.0)  
     composer_map_2.setGridEnabled(True)  

     grid_interval = 500.0
     composer_map_2.setGridIntervalX(grid_interval)  
     composer_map_2.setGridIntervalY(grid_interval)  
     composer_map_2.setGridPenWidth(0.1)  
     composer_map_2.setGridFrameWidth(1.5)  
     composer_map_2.setGridFrameStyle(QgsComposerMap.Zebra)  
     composer_map_2.setGridFramePenSize(0.2)  
     composer_map_2.setGridPenColor(QColor(0, 176, 246))  
     composer_map_2.setGridBlendMode(QPainter.CompositionMode_DestinationOver)  
     composer_map_2.setShowGridAnnotation(True)  
     composer_map_2.setGridStyle(QgsComposerMap.Cross)  

     composer_map_2.setGridAnnotationPosition(QgsComposerMap.Disabled, QgsComposerMap.Top)
     composer_map_2.setGridAnnotationPosition(QgsComposerMap.OutsideMapFrame, QgsComposerMap.Bottom)
     composer_map_2.setGridAnnotationDirection(QgsComposerMap.Horizontal, QgsComposerMap.Bottom)
     composer_map_2.setGridAnnotationPosition(QgsComposerMap.OutsideMapFrame, QgsComposerMap.Left)
     composer_map_2.setGridAnnotationDirection(QgsComposerMap.Vertical, QgsComposerMap.Left)
     composer_map_2.setGridAnnotationPosition(QgsComposerMap.Disabled, QgsComposerMap.Right)

     composer.addComposerMap(composer_map_2)
     #FIN DEL SEGUNDO MAPA

     iface.mapCanvas().freeze(False)

     # **IMPRESION DEL PDf**
    printer = QPrinter() 
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat) 
    pdf_output_filename = "mapa.pdf"
    path_file_output = "D:/Descargas/mapa.pdf"
    printer.setOutputFileName(path_file_output)
    printer.setPaperSize(QSizeF(composer.paperWidth(),
                                composer.paperHeight()),
                         QPrinter.Millimeter) 
    printer.setFullPage(True) 
    printer.setColorMode(QPrinter.Color)
    printer.setResolution(composer.printResolution()) 
    pdfPainter = QPainter(printer) 
    paperRectMM = printer.pageRect(QPrinter.Millimeter)
    paperRectPixel = printer.pageRect(QPrinter.DevicePixel)
    composer.render(pdfPainter,
                    paperRectPixel,
                    paperRectMM)
    pdfPainter.end() # Ends painting
```

The composers are working well, the zoom is OK,and I can see in QGIS that the layers are enabled and disabled during the process, but the result I get is the same printing in all the maps. 
It seems like if the printer only 'remember' the last configuration, instead of each configuration for each map....

Maybe there is a function to print in PDF only a Map, and after that do the others?

I know this can be done in qgis GUI with an atlas and blocking de view, so I tried to use de freeze() function, but still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved the problem using `setLayerSet()`. 
For each `QgsComposerMap` I set up a list with the layers I wanted to be visible in each map and I've used `setLayerSet()` to establish this list in each map.

For make it more clear, the code for one of the maps will be the following:

```
#Set the layers you want to be visible in the map. 
capasMapa1 = [layer_C.id(),layer_B.id(),layer_A.id(),layer_RGB.id()] 

# Create the QGsComposerMap
composer_map = QgsComposerMap(composer, 
                              map_origin_x_mm,
                              map_origin_y_mm,
                              map_width_mm,
                              map_height_mm)

#SetLayerSet: Select the layers to use in this map.
composer_map.setLayerSet(capasMapa1)
composer_map.setKeepLayerSet(True)
```

Doing this for all the maps (changing the name of each list of layers and changing the name of each `QGsComposerMap`), I finally get the correct composition in which I had 3 maps, and different visible layers in each one.